# Pycurl Import Error: SSL Backend Mismatch

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, virtualbox, pycurl

I'm having issues with link-time and compile-time ssl backend errors when trying to import pycurl into a python script.  This script ran fine on OSX, however not on my current setup.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS on VirtualBox, Host OS Win10, Python 2.7.12, using pycurl-7.43.0.1.  The error I receive is `ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (nss)`.  I've tried uninstalling and then executing `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl` before reinstalling again with no success.  Any help is appreciated, let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing dependencies remedied through `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install openssl-devel` for Red Hat and CentOS, etc.